# Chrome Extension - Is it possible to control file input programatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What my extension does - is posts one blog post to several sites.
The sites accept image uploads via `<input type="file"/>`.
What I'd like to do is have the User upload the image once into the extn UI, and then have the extn programatically\automatically post that image in several blog posts.
My extn already has an image available as base64 string. I want to supply that image to the site, without having to select image manually from disk.
Is that somehow possible with Chrome extensions APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Because a 'select file' window belongs to the OS and chrome extension has zero control over it.

What I have found though, is that I can achieve what I need by turning my `base64 string` into a `Blob`, and then send it as a part of `FormData` object in the http request. Works just fine.

Here's a working example:

```js
// Create blob.
const url = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RiDRXhpZgAATU0AKgA...";
const blob = (await fetch(url)).blob()

// Create form data.
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', blob, 'image.jpg')

// Send blob to a server that expects a file
fetch('https://server.url', {method: 'POST', body: formData})
```